# Implementing agile with part time employees?

Tags: agile

Current organisation wants to become more agile, but there is a lot of task switching amongst employees who cannot commit a full working week on a project. It is impossible for me to run Scrum effectively since the burn down chart goes out of whack as soon as task switching takes place, hence preferred method is kanban.

What approaches would you recommend to implement agile taking this into account, I have so far factored this into my time scales by adding padding but it feels very waterfall.

Comment: Can you shed some light on the current problems? Scrum does not need a standard 40h work-week. You could do Scrum with everybody putting in 30 minutes a week. Are your employees on a fixed part-time schedule (i.e. 25h a week) or is the problem that you don't know how many hours they will work in a given sprint?

Answer (score 2):

From your statement, it is clear that you are working on a `hybrid model` of so called 'Agile' model. Please note that the process(es) does not carry any discrimination between the domain, technical stack and the resources. This hybrid model of working is the key challenge you are facing. Expecting returns from a hybrid-agile model shall remain as a far cry.

Scrum is not for generating reports rather to ensure you have effective inputs to perform thereby helping you to achieve the desirable results - consider it as a defensive project management tool.

`Agile model is meant to be implemented from the buyer's perspective by-default.`  I hope you are able to catch this point.

**Question for you:** `When you say, employees cannot commit a full working week, does that mean that their priorities keep changing? Is it because your business goal is a service-desk?`

I am guessing service-desk because you mentioned you have adapted 'Kanban' as your approach. Kanban when not implemented without understanding the requirements will again lead to failure. Ideally, Kanban can be very well implemented for UX development, Service or Business layer development, etc.It would be immensely helpful for the team to tighten up the nuts and bolts and would avoid wastage in the long run.

**Scenario analysis:**

Well, prior accepting the process-framework or the model, you might need to understand your current scenario. For example, you could pull-out your historical data (the more the better), and analyze the situation using tools such as Pareto, and fish-bone. This would help you understand the gap - where exactly do you want to fit in, How would you want to take it further and many such more.

**Adapting Agile**

Agile is fine. That could be your organization mandate. That's okay. But you, your team, your organization and your Customer have to be highly committed and should have the mindset to change the thinking towards Agile.

This will help you to advance further as only you and your team would know what exactly your Customer's objectives are. Do you, agree?

**Agility - What's the approach?**

For a service based approach, the ideal way is to apply ITSM/ITIL. Oh yes, not to worry, you could very well apply Agile with ITIL as well. You will still be on track. The new jargons that are used following the Cloud Computing model is 'DevOps'.

`DevOps` is nothing but Development and Operations; meaning you will get to manage both the development track and the IT operations.

Please do remember that these are just techno-management tools to empower you and your Team. However, you will need to work with your Customer (could be an Internal or an External), to understand what their wants are. However (ah, again!), you will need to do your homework to gain a thorough understanding on the pattern of your current scenario.

Hope this helps you.

Should you have any questions, please shoot.